# Flv playback playheadupdate interval in milliseconds i.e seek to non keyframe

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback, seek

I am having trouble catching events of playhead update in the milli second range . This is in regards to FLV playback of a loaded  flv movie.
As per the docs the seek() function seeks to keyframes,it takes time as input with the accuracy of milliseconds. 
i have a function called next frame where i pause the video and try to seek to a given playheadTime

```
    function onNextFrame(event:Event)
    {
        if (video1.playing)
        {
            video1.stop();
        }
        playHeadTime=Number(playHeadTime.toFixed(2));
        trace("Calling nextFrame :::",playHeadTime);
        trace(" Before seek ",video1.playheadTime);
        video1.seek(playHeadTime);
        playHeadTime +=  0.1;
    }
```

I have also a seek event which does not update for every seek but rather only on the occurrence of a key frame in the flv video

```
function onseeked(event:Event)
        {
            trace("seeked",video1.playheadTime);
        }
```

I also have a playhead update event to track the playhead movement 
but this does not update on using the next frame function. it works only when the video is playing normally.

```
video1.playheadUpdateInterval = 30;
video1.seekToPrevOffset = 0.01;
video1.addEventListener(VideoEvent.SEEKED,onseeked);
video1.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE,onPlayHeadUpdate);
function onseeked(event:Event)
        {
            trace("seeked",video1.playheadTime);
        }
```

My question is

- How do i make the playhead update  in milliseconds accuracy  when the video is paused/stoped and seeked to a time.
- How do i update the playhead in the first place when seek only seems to work to a keyframe. How do i get the seek to a non keyframe  time?

A relevant discussion regarding this but which also does not provide any solution is

[How to jump to a non-keyframe in a flv player](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=172910)

---

Update: 
Even with the netstream.seek()  each consecutive call to the function does not show a change in video.playheadtime.It works the same way as video.seek().

```
video.playheadtime=0.1
```

This kind of assignment too does not work in making the playhead property change/update.

**How can we achieve fast forward/fast rewind action?**

Comment: Doesn't it totally depend on how many keyframes you have in your encoded FLV? The more keyframes = bigger filesize = more accuracy for seeking, right?

Comment: Documentation says seek will go the nearest keyframe.  If you want more accuracy, you'll have to seek to the previous keyframe, play it, listening for playhead update events, check the playhead time, and pause it immediately after it passes the time you want.  For additional accuracy in the playhead update time, set the playheadUpdateInterval to 1000 / stage.framerate, because the default is a quarter second (250ms), which it's very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

check if flv metadata has `canseekontime = false`
also check if `NetStream.seek(12.222/*milliseconds/1000*/)` works for the same flv

Comment: do recieve `keyframes = [object Object] (times, filepositions)` in metadata?

Comment: trace the key frame positions time stamp and use that to seek? we wont get the inbetween's. in fast /slow